# Loop through Dictionary in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have `var countriesGroupedByRegion: Dictionary<String, [Array<Country>.Element]>`
The key (String) is the region and the array are all the countries within that region.

I need to loop through this dictionary so I can create a List with as much sections as regions, and within each section, I want to show all the countries... but I don't know how to loop through this dictionary in SwiftUI using ForEach. My current code is the following:

```
NavigationView {
  List {
    ForEach(countriesGroupedByRegion, id: \.self) { region in
                    
    }
  }
}
```

where `countriesGroupedByRegion` is the mentioned dictionary. I get the following error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<String, [Array<Country>.Element]>'`

Could someone help me figure out how to loop through this dict and create the sections in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to map the (keys of the) dictionary to an array of a region struct

```
struct Region { 
    let name : String
    let countries : [Country]
}
```

This can be used in a `ForEach` statement with `id: \.name`. Further consider that a dictionary is unordered.

This is a simple example with a string array representing the countries

```
let dictionary = ["Asia": ["Japan", "India"], "Europe": ["Italy", "Norway"]]

struct Region {
    let name : String
    let countries : [String]
}

let regions = dictionary
    .keys
    .sorted()
    .map{Region(name: $0, countries: dictionary[$0]!)}
```

---

```
NavigationView {
  List {
    ForEach(regions, id: \.name) { region in
                    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Breaking up the keys and then force unwrapping, not so good as `dictionary.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }.map(Region.init)`. I use a Sequence extension to do it like `dictionary.sorted(by: \.key).map(Region.init)`.

Comment: @Jessy Force unwrapping is fine because a standard Swift dictionary cannot have `nil` values. And calling `map` on a dictionary creates an array of tuples which is – with regard to efficiency – pretty much the same.